# How to wait for a set of child processes (and only them) without polling and without eating up the exit code of other people child processes?

Tags: c++, linux, pipe, child-process

How to wait for a set of child processes (and only them) without polling and without eating up the exit code of other people child processes?

Is it an idea, to create a pipe for every fd 0 of every child and use select() to wait for these fds?

Would one have to use the exceptfds parameter of select()?

Comment: The pipe technique should work. You don't need `exceptfds`, EOF is not an error.

Comment: This is for a library function that wants to be usable in a program that creates its own independent children? This is a difficult problem, because of the program has a `SIGCHLD` handler, it will be invoked when your children exit, and they'll call `wait()` on your children.

Comment: For example, this is an age-old problem with the standard `system()` function.

Comment: If you're using a recent enough kernel, you can use [`pidfd_open()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pidfd_open.2.html) instead of pipes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can make them all part of the same process group, you can use the negated process group id for `waitpid`.

For example

```
pid_t first = fork()
if(first == 0) {
  // ... thread function
  exit(0);
}
setpgid(first, 0); // creates a new process group
for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
{
  pid_t pid = fork();
  if(pid == 0)
  {
    // ... thread function
    exit(0);
  }
  setpgid(pid, first); // joins the process group
}
int status;
waitpid(-first, &status, WUNTRACED);
```

This will wait for the processes created this way, but not for other child processes, and does not eat up other exit codes.

If you intend on calling any of the `exec()` functions in the child process, you should ensure that the process group id is set before that. You can do this by setting it in both the main and child process. So for the first one, you would use

```
pid_t first = fork()
if(first == 0) {
  setpgid(0, 0);
  execv(filename, args);
}
setpgid(first, 0);
```

And `setpgid(0, first)` for the others.

You'll need to include `<unistd.h>` and `<sys/wait.h>`

Comment: As long as the `thread function ` part exits the new process. And you'll probably need a way to wait for the first child to call `setpgid()` before forking the rest of the processes.

Comment: (What happens to the process group when the leader exits while other processes in it are still running? I don't remember.)

Comment: @Shawn You are correct that this creates somewhat of a race condition (though very unlikely that this will cause an issue). An easier solution is to set the group id from the main thread. I will edit the answer.

Comment: @Shawn Nothing special happens when a process group leader exits. The group will no longer have a leader, but that doesn't matter.

Comment: From what I read in the man page for setpgid() the child process would have to wait for the parent to call setpgid() before it calls execvp(). Doesn't this require some synchronization?

Comment: @FrankPuck If you call `exec()` you should call `setpgid()` from both the child process and the main process. Since you don't have the pid in the child process, you can use `0` instead. It doesn't matter which one runs first then.